# Nvidia SLI Disabled on Windows 8. I installed thte Nvidia Windows 8 drivers

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, sli

### Details

I recently upgraded to Windows 8 Enterprise trial.
After installing, I downloaded the Nvidia Windows 8 x64 install package, and it installed fine.
After rebooting I got a message stating that SLI was disabled.
And in the configuration menu the option to enable SLI is grayed out.
I have confirmed the SLI is connected properly.

Any thoughts?

### Screenshot

[image]

### System Info

http://db.tt/kwG9ADBS

Comment: I am going to guess this has something to do with Windows 8 Enterprise.  Have you tried a non-Enterprise and non-trial version of Windows 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling the nvidia drivers for the 3rd time which corrected the issue. I was unable to isolate what the exact issue was unfortunately but it is fixed now.